# Как вывести объект со вложностью в формете json в play framework 2?

Tags: scala, playframework

У меня есть такие `case` классы:

```
case class Role(name: String)
case class User(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, role: Role)
```

И такой контроллер:

```
class MyController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def user = Action {
    val user = User(1, "Petr", "Petrov", Role("USER"))

    val userJson = Json.toJson(user)
    println(userJson)

    Ok(userJson)
  }

}
```

Согласно [документации](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) в случае, если класс User был бы без вложенности, то я мог бы сделать так:

```
implicit val userWrites = Json.writes[User]
val userJson = Json.toJson(user)

Ok(userJson)
```

Но т.к. у меня есть объект `role` в объекте `user`, это не работает.

**Как сделать правильно обработку объектов со вложностью?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявить сначала конвертер для вложенного типа, потом для внешнего - в таком случае когда будет инициализироваться переменная `userWrites` - у нее уже будет в области видимости все нужные конвертеры:

```
implicit val roleWrites = Json.writes[Role]
implicit val userWrites = Json.writes[User]
val userJson = Json.toJson(user)

Ok(userJson)
```

---

А вообще советую писать конвертеры в объектах-компаньонах самих классов, в таком случае не надо будет постоянно импортировать их в область видимости - например если ты будешь конвертировать в JSON в разных контроллерах.

Вот так:

```
case class Role(name: String)

object Role {
    implicit val toJson: Writes[Role] = Json.writes[Role]
}

case class User(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, role: Role)

object User {
    implicit val toJson: Writes[User] = Json.writes[User]
}
```

Comment: Не получается вторым способом))) http://joxi.ru/V2VEBD9T06a4lm

Comment: Укажи тип явно, типо `Json.writes[Role]`. Писал по памяти - только открывал IDE чтоб проверить :)

Comment: Отлично! Сработало)))